# Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZ"

Tags: d3.js, kendo-dataviz

am creating a d3.js and react pie chart and the path element is giving an error on the d attribute expecting a number.

Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZ".

am looking at my code and I can't figure out the problem.

```
import React from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3'

function Pie() {

    const data = [{name: 'simba', value: 60}, {name: 'kiki', value: 40}]
    const pieData = d3.pie().value(d => d.value)(data)

    const arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(50)
        
    return (
        <svg>
            <g transform={`translate(50, 50)`} >
                <path d={arc(pieData)}/>
            </g>  
        </svg>
    )
}

export default Pie
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate path element for each slice of the pie chart. Right now, you have only one path element and you are passing the entire `pieData` array to `arc`. Instead `arc` should only be passed a single element of `pieData`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import React from 'react'
    import * as d3 from 'd3'
    
    function Pie() {
    
        const data = [{name: 'simba', value: 60}, {name: 'kiki', value: 40}]
        const pieData = d3.pie().value(d => d.value)(data)
    
        const arc = d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(0)
            .outerRadius(50)
            
        return (
            <svg>
                <g transform={`translate(50, 50)`} >
                                       
                    {pieData.map((item) => (
                       <g>
                           <path d={arc(item)} stroke="white"/>
                       </g>
                    ))}               
                </g>  
            </svg>
        )
    }
    
    export default Pie
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).